# The web server does not appear to have FrontPage Server Extensions installed : visual studio 2012 iis express

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2012, clickonce, frontpage-extensions

I'm using visual studio 2012 and i have a windows form app. the iis express server is configured by default with visual studio 2012.

I have to publish my windows form app. For that, i have create a storege object on azure platform.

But when i try to publish the project using clickonce i have that issue :

Error   83 The Web server does not appear to have FrontPage Server Extensions installed. If FrontPage Server Extensions are installed, this error can occur because the _vti_bin virtual directory is not marked as executable. To correct this problem, run Internet Information Services Manager, select the Web server that has the problem, and then use the Check Server Extensions command.

Screen shot :

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B-aV0dsLT4CaemZuQV93Ymt4UVE/edit?usp=sharing

I had no issue during the creation of my storage object on azure, and the URL is good !

I have installed de FrontPage Server Extension several times and normally it's good.

i really need to publish my project, if someone can help me ...

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to do HTTP publish to a server that doesn't have FPSE installed. FPSE was no longer available after Server 2008 (I'm guessing here, I just know it's not available for newer versions of Windows Server).

Instead of doing HTTP, use FTP. So you FTP the files to the web server, and use an HTTP link for the customer to access them.

For example, your publishing file location might be

```
ftp://myserver.com/myfolder/
```

and your installation URL would be something like

```
http://myserver/thefolder/
```